# How to check for no result in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check for no result in MySQL query and return a no result message to the user. How do I integrate it with my current code?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '<div class="mydiv">';

if($row['photo']){

    echo "<p>" . '<span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>' . '</p>' . '<p>' . "<img src=http://localhost:8888/example/images/" . $row['photo'] . "><hr>";

}else
echo '<p>' . '<span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>' . $row['message'] . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . '~' . $row['username'] . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . $row['datetime'] . ' ' .'(UTC)' . '</p>';
echo '</div>';

}
```

I want a "no result" message to show up when there are no records found. How do I integrate it in my existing code. Please advise.

```
if ($row = mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
echo "<h3>There are no result found.</h3>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($result = mysql_query($sql) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // there are results in $result
    // whatever you want to do with your results
} else {
    // no results
echo "<h3>There are no results found.</h3>";
}
```

Comment: Under the note "There are results", this is where you will add any code you want to go through when there results, in your case, echoing the various paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you. It works! I tweaked it a little bit to:

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// there are results in $result
// whatever you want to do with your results
} else {
// no results
echo "<h3>There are no results found.</h3>";
}